# Losing leading "0" Zeros when converting to integer from string

Tags: java, android, integer, int

I am losing the leading zeros from my variable when I am converting it from a `String` to an `Integer`,

```
String[] parts = Firsttt.split(":");
String part1 = parts[0]; // Hour
String part2 = parts[1]; // Minute
Integer part1int = (Integer.valueOf(part1));
part1int++;
Firsttt = part1int +":"+ part2;
```

Is there a correct way to do this without loosing the leading zero or should I just alter the  result to include the zero again ?

i.e:     `Firsttt = "0" + part1int +":"+ part2;`

the problem with adding the zero again is that the variable doesn't always include a zero so just checking that there isn't a better way.
Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An `Integer` doesn't have leading zeros, or any other formatting property. It is just a number.

If you want the printout to include a leading zero, I recommend using [`String#format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29). To always get a leading `0` if `part1Int` is below `10`, use:

```
String.format("%02d:%s", part1Int, part2);
```

Comment: had the same problem in my answer. part2 is already `String`, so `%s` instead :)

Comment: hi, so %02d is formatting the number to 2 integers?

Comment: I assume you mean 2 digits not 2 integers.  What "%02d" means is "format a string from an integer that will be at least 2 digits wide, and if it is less than 2 digits wide, pad with leading 0's".  If you change the 2 to some other number (except 1), same rule applies.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and yes I couldn't think of the correct word, thanks.

Comment: Using this in eclipse gives a Lint Marker "Implicitly using the default locale is a common source of bugs: Use String.format(Locale, ...) instead" is this important?

Comment: I think it is just a generic warning in case the characters aren't what you're expecting them to be in a foreign language?

Answer (score 2):

if you don't want to go for a fancy `String.format()`, you can use your own way as

```
if (part1int / 10 > 0) {
    Firsttt = part1int + ":" + part2;
} else {
    Firsttt = "0" + part1int + ":" + part2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could either add the leading zero if and only if part1int is below 10 or use some formatting with padding 0 :

```
Firsttt = String.format("%02d:%d", part1int, part2);
```

Comment: Hi, Im getting an "unknown format conversion exception" with this?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
Firsttt = String.format("%02d:%s", part1int, part2);
```

this will add the leading zeros *if necessary*.